For what purpose is it said that the soul is immortal if only God is immortal?
The text of the Orthodox Divine Service speaks of salvation from the destruction of the human race and nowhere speaks of the immortality of the soul.

Welcome to the site. Are you asking about Orthodox Divine Service or just about the topic of immortality that members can answer from the Scriptures? It interesting to think about from the standpoint of Christ.  The Son was eternal without a beginning but the man Jesus had a beginning. The Son’s eternal life being made human and conquering death means Jesus and his soul can’t ever die. Having eternal life with a beginning means one is not absolutely immortal in the same way that the divine nature is. The limited form of immortality is obtained by the unlimited and only true immortality.

This article from an Orthodox viewpoint quotes numerous church fathers, who are unanimous in declaring the immortality of the soul: https://orthodoxy.life/2018/10/19/what-is-man/

God is eternal. He creates immortal souls.

@nigel what is a dead soul?  As in the soul that is sinning will die?

@Kris In the day he eateth shall he surely die. Then, afterwards, comes the 'second death'.

@nigel since the soul dies it is not immortal.

@Kris Adam died in the day he ate. Genesis 2:17. Yet lived to be 930 years old. Genesis 5:5. /// If we be dead with Christ we believe that we shall also live with him. Romans 6:8. I am crucified with Christ nevertheless I live yet not I but Christ liveth in me. Galatians 2:20.

So @nigel what is a day?  Is it’s 24 hours?  Did Adam’s soul die?

I'm uncertain if you are referring to a text or if you are referring to the Divine Liturgy (if so which one)
But I think the issue of if your soul is immortal is clearly stated in the Bible to such a degree that even I can answer.

And many of those who sleep in the dust of the earth shall awake, some to everlasting life, and some to shame and everlasting contempt. (Daniel 12:2)


And these will go away into eternal punishment, but the righteous into eternal life. (Matthew 25:46)


And which now has been manifested through the appearing of our Savior Christ Jesus, who abolished death and brought life and immortality to light through the gospel (2 Timothy 1:10)


When the perishable puts on the imperishable, and the mortal puts on immortality, then shall come to pass the saying that is written: “Death is swallowed up in victory.” (1 Corinthians 15:54)


In the path of righteousness is life, and in its pathway there is no death. (Proverbs 12:28)

Not to mention all the church fathers, I'll choose St Nectarios for this one.

Highlighted by St Nectarios of Aegina when he explains: “Because he became the image and likeness of God and [he] was created in order to live eternally and dwell in the same place as the heavenly angels. This is a marvellous reality, and an example of God’s supreme love for Man and his nobility in the eyes of God.” This great destiny is achieved in this life by the coworking of both soul and body. According to the teaching of St Nectarios, the body may well die, but the soul lives on and is immortal. In fact, the soul has “supernatural, infinite aspirations” according to the Saint. If the soul were not immortal, and died together with the body, then it follows that the soul would be dependent on the body.
The soul would be reliant on the body, and therefore the body is primary. The reverse is true, however, and it is in fact the soul which is master over the body. The dominance of the soul over the body is proven by the way that we submit our body to the will of the soul. Acts of self denial, sacrifice, principles and ideas are some examples of the will of the soul being expressed through the body. According to St Nectarios, such abstract ideas would be meaningless to a soul that was mortal.

Peace be with you
